# Is this a good way of parsing a string?

Tags: java, parsing

My program reads lines from a plain text file w/ lines formatted: `<integer>;<integer>%n`, where `;` is the delimiter. It compares the two parsed integers against 2 other known values and increments `tallyArray[i]` if they match.

I currently use:

```
try {
    scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("LogFileToBeRead.txt")));

    for (int i = 0; i < tallyArraySize; i++) {
        explodedLogLine = scan.nextLine().split(";");

        if (IntReferenceVal1 == Integer.parseInt(explodedLogLine[0]) && IntReferenceVal2 == Integer.parseInt(explodedLogLine[1])) {
           tallyArray[i]++;
        }
    }
} finally {
    if (scan != null) { scan.close(); }
}
```

I was wondering if there were any serious faults with this method. It does not need to be production-quality.

Also, is there a standard way of parsing a string like this?

EDIT: We can assume the text file is perfectly formatted. But I see the importance for accounting for possible exceptions.

Comment: it seems most the bad aspects come from not handling possible errors. My question is more on the way I parse the integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not handling `NumberFormatExceptions` thrown by the `Integer.parseInt()` method calls. If there's one bad line, execution exits your for loop.

You aren't vetting the integrity of the file you are reading from. If there isn't a `;` character or if the Strings aren't actually numbers, execution simply exits the code block you posted.

---

If you can assume the file is perfectly formatted, and you're set on using a Scanner, you can add `;` as a delimiter to the Scanner:

```
scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("LogFileToBeRead.txt")));
scan.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("(;|\\s)"));

for (int i = 0; i < tallyArraySize; i++) {
    int ref1 = scan.nextInt();
    int ref2 = scan.nextInt();

    if (IntReferenceVal1 == ref1 && 
        IntReferenceVal2 == ref2) {
       tallyArray[i]++;
    }
}
```

And simply call `Scanner.nextInt()` twice for each line.

Comment: Thank you for the scan.nextInt() function. This was more along the lines of what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

According to me There are three flaws in the program.

1. Delimiter `;` what if there is delimiter is removed by accident or added by accident
2. There should be check on `explodedLogLine` that it is of length `2` and it is not `null` otherwise it will result in unexpected runtime error
3. You should catch `NumberFormatException` format exception since you can never be sure that Input is always a number

A simple illustration below gives you idea how things will go wrong.

```
    String str = "3;;3";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split(";")));
```

This code will print `[3, , 3]` in such case your program will produce `NumberFormatException` as `""` string can not be parsed to Integer.